# how to apply same effect(fade in/out) on other div?

Tags: jquery, html

here is my code:

```
 var faderIndex = 0,
        faders = $('.fadey,fadey2,fadey3');

    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
                faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
```

html code:

```
<div>
    <div class='fadey'>1</div>
    <div class='fadey'>2</div>
    <div class='fadey'>3</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class='fadey2'>hello1</div>
    <div class='fadey2'>hello2</div>
    <div class='fadey2'>hello3</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class='fadey3'>hello1111</div>
    <div class='fadey3'>hello2222</div>
    <div class='fadey3'>hello33333</div>
</div>
```

css :

```
div.fadey,div.fadey2,div.fadey3 {
    display: none;
}
```

i have tried it but it doesn't work please help me?

Comment: you want the items from each group to fade independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `.` in your class selector

```
var faderIndex = 0,
faders = $('.fadey,.fadey2,.fadey3');
//-----------------^.......^.......   
function nextFade() {
    $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        faderIndex++;
        if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
            faderIndex = 0;
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
    });
}
nextFade();
```

You can change this

```
faders = $('.fadey,.fadey2,.fadey3');
```

to

```
faders = $('[class^=fadey]');
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/dyTZ6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

What about

`[class*="fadey"]`
To target all elements that have string 'fadey' as a part of class name, so you don't need to update css and jQuery code when you add more faders (fadey4, fadey5, etc)?